# Lightning Node Full Pubkey

Tags: lightning-network

I have my lnd node pubkey, public IP address and an open port as follows:

0286712a3a81b0d5e54469042146137fbdf7b77802f21fad1261c031a8d917f5da@...

Do I have to set parameters after the '@' sign - in some configuration file or is it enough to just use them when I provide the full address?

Comment: You could just test if your node is reachable from outside: just tested and it is, congrats! :)

Comment: @darosior - thanks for checking and confirming!